# Problemas de Consulta entre Java y Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas estoy trabajando en un proyecto entre Java y MySQL. 
Se están agregando datos en una base de datos en MYSQL, pero al momento de realizar las consultas con la tabla me esta dando muchos errores. 
La tabla como tal tiene los siguientes datos:

```sql
`dn_cliente` (
  `identificacion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Apellido1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Apellido2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fecha_Nacimiento` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tipo_Sangre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tipo_Rh` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Padecimiento` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tiene_Hijo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cant_Hijos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tiene_Padre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tiene_Madre` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Familiar_Adicional` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parentezco` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Donador` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL)
```

He generado los metodos necesarios para hacer adecuadamente el Insert en la base, pero no soy tan diestro para realizar las consultas y sacar la informacion.

De donde se requiere de traer cierta informacion:

```js
    public List<Donador> consultaxTipo_Sangre(String Tipo_Sangre) {
        try {
            if (this.con.conectarse()) {
                this.sentencia = this.con.getCon().prepareStatement("select * from donalocr.dn_cliente where Tipo_Sangre=?");
                this.sentencia.setString(1, Tipo_Sangre);
               
                List<Donador> listat = new ArrayList<>();
                ResultSet resultado = this.sentencia.executeQuery();
                while (resultado.next()) {
                    Donador don = new Donador();
                    don.setNombre(resultado.getString("nombre"));
                    don.setApellido1(resultado.getString("Apellido1"));
                    don.setApellido1(resultado.getString("Apellido2"));
                    don.setFecha_nac(resultado.getString("Fecha_Nacimiento"));
                    don.setTipo_sangre(resultado.getString("Tipo_Sangre"));
                    don.setTipo_rh(resultado.getString("Tipo_Rh"));
                    don.setPadecimiento(resultado.getString("Padecimiento"));
                    don.setT_hijos(resultado.getString("Tiene_Hijo"));
                    don.setCant_hijos(resultado.getInt("Cant_Hijos"));
                    don.setT_padre(resultado.getString("Tiene_Padre"));
                    don.setT_madre(resultado.getString("Tiene_Madre"));
                    don.setFamiliar(resultado.getString("Familiar_Adicional"));
                    don.setDona_org(resultado.getString("Donador"));
                    don.setCiudad(resultado.getString("Ciudad"));
                    don.setEstados(resultado.getString("Estado"));
                    don.setPais(resultado.getString("Pais"));
                    listat.add(don);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, don);
                }
                this.con.desconectarse();
                return listat;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Este es el código para la consulta.
Ocupaba tomar los datos del id. tipo de sangre, tipo de rh y padecimiento, pero no logro realizar la consulta adecuda. 
 Pero me envía el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1365)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1378)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1745)
    at Dao.DonadorDao.consultaxTipo_Sangre(DonadorDao.java:288)
    at Bo.DonadorBo.consultaxTipo_Sangre(DonadorBo.java:57)
    at Donadores.Busqueda_Donadores.llenarTabla(Busqueda_Donadores.java:707)
    at Donadores.Busqueda_Donadores.buscar(Busqueda_Donadores.java:692)
    at Donadores.Busqueda_Donadores.jb_buscar_sangreActionPerformed(Busqueda_Donadores.java:600)
    at Donadores.Busqueda_Donadores.access$000(Busqueda_Donadores.java:31)
    at
```

Comment: Sería bueno saber que líneas o fragmento de código marca error ya que con lo que proporcionas solo te puedo decir que en algún lugar de todo el código estas dando un quinto parámetro pero realmente solo tiene uno (tipo_sangre), sigue el hilo de llamadas dado por st1acktracer

Comment: el error lo da este metodo: Dao.DonadorDao.consultaxTipo_Sangre, no el que pasaste...

Comment: Listo he hecho la modificacion de la consulta!

Comment: Los errores son: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 1).
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1365)

Comment: El error me lo da despues del Preparestatement, en este punto:   this.sentencia = this.con.getCon().prepareStatement("select * from donalocr.dn_cliente where Tipo_Sangre=?");
                this.sentencia.setString(1, Tipo_Sangre);